# Oracle SQL Multi Column <> Null Select

Tags: sql, oracle, identity-column

```
SELECT * 
FROM GNGRB.LOAN 
WHERE LOAN, INTRST, RATE IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY LOAN DESC;
```

Please identify the error in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see `loan`, `interest` and `rate` is all `number` data type values, you can use + as follows:

```
Select * from your_table t
 Where loan + interest + rate is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM GNGRB.LOAN 
WHERE LOAN IS NOT NULL
  AND INTRST IS NOT NULL
  AND RATE IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY LOAN DESC;
```

Comment: This looks a corrected version of the code from the question - which asked to *identify* the error rather than asking to correct it. Can you pinpoint where the original went wrong and what has been wrong about it?

Comment: It appears the initial problem stems from an incorrect assumption that a "distributive property" is in play. **This does not happen is SQL.**. The property (in this case "is not null") does not apply across variables/columns/expressions but must individually applied to each. Then each resulting predicate must have a logical connector to any previous or following predicates. Thus "(RATE is not null) **and** (LOAN is not null) ...". The version by @Popeye works because "anything + null always results in null".